# Много таблиц, как быть с миграцией

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, mvc

Всем привет. У меня в базе много таблиц. Я использую entity framework.
Вот что у получается в моделях базы.

[image: Скриншот обозревателя решений]

Как видно моделей таблиц уже много, и они будут еще добавляться. Можно как-нибудь поубавить кол-во кода?

Comment: Я как-то пробегал мимо банковского проекта... банк из Китая.... вот там на проэкте мнооооооого таблиц.... а здесь таблиц, можно сказать, нету вообще)

Comment: но всё же для каждой таблицы нужно писать новую модель. много времени уходит, если каждый раз нужно добавлять новую таблицу

Comment: _поубавить кол-во кода_ - Выделить - Удалить.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Если с данными нужно работать - нужен способ делать это. OK, вместо создания моделей и репозиториев можно фигачить сырые sql-запросы на ADO.NET. Только не забудьте припасти верёвку, мыло и табуретку.

Comment: В каждой задаче есть сложность присущая и побочная (inherent и incidental). Если у вас в предметной области 100 типов сущностей, то никуда вы от этого не денетесь - это присущая сложность, нужно их все как-то представить в ПО. Тут возможная проблема - неадекватное моделирование предметной области. Другое дело, если при этом вам нужно проделывать одни и те же монотонные действия с кучей copy-and-paste, это уже побочная сложность, от которой нужно и должно избавиться. Но чтоб помочь, что с моделированием, что с побочной сложностью, нам нужно видеть примеры конкретных проблем.